# How to add the play, stop... button to a video

Tags: iphone, objective-c

i use this code to display a video in my app

```
NSURL *movieUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:
                       [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"myvideoname" 
                                                       ofType:@"mp4"]];

    //create a new instance of MPMoviePlayerController
    MPMoviePlayerController* myMovie=[[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] 
                                      initWithContentURL:movieUrl];

    //disable scaling of our movie
    myMovie.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeNone;
    [myMovie.view setFrame: myView.bounds];  // player's frame must match parent's
    [myView addSubview: myMovie.view];

    [[myMovie view] setFrame:[myView bounds]];
    //don't show any controls
   // myMovie.movieControlMode = MPMovieControlModeHidden;

    //you can specify at which time the movie should 
    //start playing (default is 0.0)
    myMovie.initialPlaybackTime = 2.0;

    //register a callback method which will be called
    //after the movie finished
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                             selector:@selector(movieFinished:) 
                                                 name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification 
                                               object:myMovie]; 
    myMovie.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeAspectFill;

    //start the movie (asynchronous method)
    [myMovie play];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
```

it work fine but i want to add the controls ( play , stop , sound control ...)
How can i do ? thanx

Answer (score 0):

What using [controlStyle](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/MPMoviePlayerController/controlStyle)?

```
myMovie.constrolStyle = MPMovieControlStyleEmbedded;
```

MPMovieControlStyle
Constants describing the style of the playback controls.

```
enum {
   MPMovieControlStyleNone,
   MPMovieControlStyleEmbedded,
   MPMovieControlStyleFullscreen,
   MPMovieControlStyleDefault = MPMovieControlStyleFullscreen
};
typedef NSInteger MPMovieControlStyle;
```

> Constants
>
> **MPMovieControlStyleNone** 
>   No controls are displayed. Available in
>   iOS 3.2 and later. Declared in
>   MPMoviePlayerController.h.
>
> **MPMovieControlStyleEmbedded**
>   Controls for an embedded view are displayed.
>   The controls include a start/pause
>   button, a scrubber bar, and a button
>   for toggling between fullscreen and
>   embedded display modes. Available in
>   iOS 3.2 and later. Declared in
>   MPMoviePlayerController.h.
>
> **MPMovieControlStyleFullscreen**
>   Controls for fullscreen playback are displayed.
>   The controls include a start/pause
>   button, a scrubber bar, forward and
>   reverse seeking buttons, a button for
>   toggling between fullscreen and
>   embedded display modes, a button for
>   toggling the aspect fill mode, and a
>   Done button. Tapping the done button
>   pauses the video and exits fullscreen
>   mode. Available in iOS 3.2 and later.
>   Declared in MPMoviePlayerController.h.
>
> **MPMovieControlStyleDefault**
>   Fullscreen controls are displayed by default.
>   Available in iOS 3.2 and later.
>   Declared in MPMoviePlayerController.h.
>   MPMovieFinishReason

Answer (score 0):

You should set the [control style](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/Reference/Reference.html), like `myMovie.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleDefault;` to add a control bar.

Comment: @Henrik @texmex5 thank you for answer . I added myMovie.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleEmbedded; nut nothing change . and i havint understand where shoul i put the enum :( i putted it in .h , .m i alwayse have error ...

Comment: You don't have to add the enum to your header file. Only line you need to add is myMovie.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleEmbeded.

Answer (score 0):

Define the `controlStyle` property on the `MPMoviePlayerController` object.

**Constants describing the style of the playback controls.**

```
enum {
   MPMovieControlStyleNone,
   MPMovieControlStyleEmbedded,
   MPMovieControlStyleFullscreen,
   MPMovieControlStyleDefault = MPMovieControlStyleFullscreen
};
typedef NSInteger MPMovieControlStyle;
```

Read more from [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/MPMovieControlStyle)